# Call function on default when checkboxes are rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, react-redux, redux-saga

```js
this.state.pageData.map((elem) =>
  elem.map((ele) => {
    this.props.AllSelectedFlag ? (
      <Td>
        {' '}
        <Input type="checkbox" value={ele.id} checked={true} onClick={(e) => this.selectHandle(e, ele)} />
      </Td>
    ) : (
      <Td>
        <Input type="checkbox" value={ele.id} onClick={(e) => this.selectHandle(e, ele)} />
      </Td>
    );
  }),
);
```

Basically I have to check all the checkboxes when select all button is pressed, I am changing the state of AllSelectedFlag when button is pressed, but the problem is onClick button is not working when the condition is true.

Any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 1: If you have "checked" property

You don't need to render and apply check properties for checkboxes, you just need to set "checked" property for all elements on "all" selection and reset.

And you can add event onChange on each checkboxes that will be used for individual check/uncheck part.

Refer to example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vvxpny4xq3

Approach 2: if you dont have "checked" property in json

Maintain local array with "ids" inside and oncheck/uncheck add/remove from it and use it for handling check related cases

```
    const [isCheckAll, setIsCheckAll] = useState(false);
    const [isCheck, setIsCheck] = useState([]);
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    const handleSelectAll = e => {
        setIsCheckAll(!isCheckAll);
        setIsCheck(list.map(li => li.id));
        if (isCheckAll) {
          setIsCheck([]);
        }
    };

    const handleClick = e => {
        const { id, checked } = e.target;
        setIsCheck([...isCheck, id]);
        if (!checked) {
          setIsCheck(isCheck.filter(item => item !== id));
        }
    };
```

Refer to example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-all-checkbox-jbub2

Comment: Will onChange work if i use prop to change the state?

Comment: onChange will be triggered whenever you try to change check status, then you can change state of parent using handler function (this handler function will be available via props)

Comment: Sorry, had one more issue, in my case data is coming from an API and there is no ischecked key in the data, how should i proceed any ideas?

Comment: Answer is updated, please refer to approach 2. Its for hooks based implementation you can implement similarly for class based as well